# WPF MVVM open new window on top of Parent Window and set parent window as Owner of Childwindow

Tags: wpf, mvvm, childwindow, modalpopup

My question is related to following article where you posted your answer.

Ref: [open child window inside a parent window in wpf using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446825/open-child-window-inside-a-parent-window-in-wpf-using-mvvm)

I am using MVVM framework and the technique you have mentioned in your following post

http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/

This is the same technique I am using to implement my WPF application. I am building new WPF application and want to use pure MVVM i.e. no code behind.
Now I want to open dialog window or Child Window on top of application window using a button click on current application window. In that window I want to show some data in data grid and want to give facility to filer those data in grid to search specific data in grid and then want to give user a functionality where user can select specific row from grid and hit "OK" or "Cancel".
Now my problem is How can I open this window on top of application window? How can I know that which record user have selected? and once user click "OK" or "Cancel" I want that window to go away and do some operation based on selection.

Do you have any sample for this scenario? Or could you give any sample for this scenario?
I can share my solution with you if you want.

Thanks in Advance.

Mitesh.

Answer (score -3):

It seems to me that you are at the start and need some input for learning. Try the links in the following post that is marked as the answer:

[MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)

Comment: Ok. Sure I will follow the link you have mentioned above in your answer. Thanks.